# Some lines remained in Sheet1 when they are supposed to be in Sheet5

Tags: excel, vba

The code is supposed to separate cells by finding the word "BREAK" and all the lines below it before another word "BREAK." The problem is that the first to fourth "BREAK" and the lines below it was successfully transferred to other sheets but the last word "BREAK" was in Sheet5 with 1 line below it but the other lines remained in the first sheet.

I have editing some parts but it is still not working

```
Sub Fails()
    Dim mFind As Range
    Dim Compteur As Integer
    Dim IdSheet As Integer
    Dim ErrorBool As Boolean

    debut:
    Set mFind = Columns("A").Find("Break")
    Set mfind2 = Columns("A").Find("Break")
    If mFind Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There is no cell found with the text 'Break'" _
        & " in column A of the active sheet."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    firstaddress = mFind.Address
    IdSheet = 1
    Compteur = 0
    Do
            Set mfind2 = Columns("A").FindNext(mFind)
            If mfind2 Is Nothing Then
            Else:
            If mFind.Row < mfind2.Row Then
             Compteur = mfind2.Row
            End If
            If mFind.Row > mfind2.Row Then
             ErrorBool = True
            End If

            If ErrorBool = True Then
            Range(mFind, Cells(mFind.Row + 1, "A")).EntireRow.Cut
            End If
            End If

            Range("A" & mFind.Row + 1 & ":A" & Compteur - 1).EntireRow.Cut
            If mFind Is Nothing Then
            Else: IdSheet = IdSheet + 1
            End If
            Sheets("Sheet" & IdSheet & "").Select
            Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

    line:
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Range(mFind, Cells(mFind.Row, "A")).EntireRow.Delete
        Set mFind = Columns("A").Find("Break")
        Set mfind2 = Columns("A").Find("Break")
        If mFind Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set mFind = Columns("A").FindNext(mFind)

    Loop While mFind.Address <> firstaddress
End Sub
```

Sheet5 should have all the information under the last "Break"

Sheet1:

[image]

Sheet5:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to debug your program ? Execute it step by step (F8) and try to see where it behaves different as you expect.

Comment: Yes @FunThomas, the last part is my problem. I have been trying to fix it for hours, still no luck. "line:
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range(mFind, Cells(mFind.Row, "A")).EntireRow.Delete
    Set mFind = Columns("A").Find("Break")
    Set mfind2 = Columns("A").Find("Break")
    If mFind Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set mFind = Columns("A").FindNext(mFind)"